# atos cannot load symbols for the file error

Tags: terminal, command, store

My app is rejected and want to know which line of source is problem.

anyway, I extracted .app file and .app.dSYM file and put it in same new directory.

Crash log says.

```
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001838d42e8 0x1838b2000 + 140008
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001839e92f8 0x1839e6000 + 13048
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000183842fbc 0x1837e0000 + 405436
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000182fdf068 0x182fdd000 + 8296
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000182fdf210 0x182fdd000 + 8720
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000183008810 0x183000000 + 34832
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000182ff754c 0x182fdd000 + 107852
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000182ff7158 0x182fdd000 + 106840
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001830086e8 0x183000000 + 34536
9   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183c84cc4 0x183c7c000 + 36036
10  GraphicsServices                0x0000000185b30f84 0x185b26000 + 44932
11  UIKit                           0x000000018d3dd5c4 0x18d36a000 + 472516
12  ARlocator  <- this is app name              0x0000000102415434 0x102410000 + 21556
```

on terminal I commanded

atos -arch arm64 -o ARlocator.app/ARlocator -l 0x102410000 0x0000000102415434

but it says 
atos cannot load symbols for the file ARlocator.app/ARlocator for architecture arm64.

Comment: It looks like your dSYM file was not built for the arm64 architecture. What is the output of `file <path-to-your-dSYM>`?

Answer (score 0):

The dSYM is a bundle. The target dwarf data is in ../contents/resources/dwarf.